# Zurb Foundation 6 XY Grid using Grid Container within Flex-Container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am using ZURB foundation 6 with XY grid and have run into a little problem and most likely something I'm doing wrong.

I want to center elements vertically so I use

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x align-middle">
      <div class="small-6 cell">Vertically Centered Left Column</div>
      <div class="small-6 cell">Vertically Centered Left Column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And using jQuery I set the height of flex-container by using `windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();`

Voila the items are vertically aligned... However two issues arise from this:

1. `small-6 cell` has a width of 50% that is not being respected and shrinks down to the approx length of the text.
2. `flex-container` unlike `grid-container` does not have a width or padding.

*To resolve the issue I added some CSS like so:*

```
.flex-container .align-middle {
    max-width: 62.5rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

So while I've patched the issue I can't help thinking that there must be an easier way, a proper way using just classes. It seems odd that grid-container is setup to do so but flex-container is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that with `flex-container`, the `grid-x` element will, along being a flex container of its own, also become a flex *row* item, having the default `flex` item value `0 1 auto`.

This means the `grid-x` won't grow wider than its content, hence `width: 50%` won't work on its children (`small-6`), as their parent doesn't have a width set.

By adding e.g. `flex-child-grow` or `cell` to the `grid-x` element, it will fill its parent's width, and the inner flex items will start behave as expected.

*Note 1: With `grid-container` this is not needed since it is not a flex container, where the `grid-x` is a normal `div`, displayed as `flex`, which, like a `block` element, by default take full width of its parent.*

*Note 2: Both `flex-container` and `grid-container` does have a default width of 100%, it is the `grid-x`, when being a flex item, that cause the issue not taking its parent's width by default.*

Stack snippet

```css
/*  for demo purpose  */ 
body            { margin: 0; }
.flex-container { height: 100vh; }
.grid-x         { border: 1px solid red; }
.small-6        { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-child-grow grid-x grid-padding-x align-middle">
      <div class="small-6 cell">Vertically Centered Left Column</div>
      <div class="small-6 cell">Vertically Centered Left Column</div>
    </div>
</div>
```